# UITableView Cell display issue

Tags: swift, uitableview, ios-autolayout

[image: screenShot when keyboard is appear][image: Image wheh keyboard is not present][image: Image of the storyboar :]

I have a UITableView, its top and bottom distance to superview is 0.
When keyboard appears I update the bottom constraint, so that keyboard will not hide the table. But on updating the bottom constraint, last two or three cells are not completely visible. I am using following code to update the bottom constraint.

```
func keyboardWillChangeFrameWithNotification(notification: NSNotification, showsKeyboard: Bool) {
let userInfo = notification.userInfo!
    let animationDuration: NSTimeInterval = (userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! NSNumber).doubleValue

    // Convert the keyboard frame from screen to view coordinates.
    let keyboardScreenBeginFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()

    if showsKeyboard
    {
       cntInputViewBottom.constant = keyboardScreenBeginFrame.size.height

    }
    else
    {
         cntInputViewBottom.constant = 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Aashish, can you add some pics of the storyboard and the simulator screenshot when it's hidden.

Comment: The view with send is there at the bottom right, so you need to add that height to the constraint and try.

Comment: Option 1: You also need to deduct height of your custom input view. Option 2: Add your custom inputview as input accessoryView of ViewController, then it will automatically manage it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey`. This is size of the keyboard at the beginning of frame change animation. You should better use `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` in order to get final frame.

Comment: The height of the keyboard will be the same in both the cases. Only the y position changes. So anything should work ideally.

Comment: Y position **does** matter.

Answer (score 0):

if x is the height of the view with send button.

```
if showsKeyboard
{
   cntInputViewBottom.constant = keyboardScreenBeginFrame.size.height+ x

}
else
{
     cntInputViewBottom.constant = x
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you are not informing your view/controller to update your constraint before and after.

```
if showsKeyboard
{
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded() 
    cntInputViewBottom.constant = keyboardScreenBeginFrame.size.height
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
else
{
     self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
     cntInputViewBottom.constant = 0
     self.view.layoutIfNeeded()      
}
```

just add `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` before & after updating constraint as displayed.